# Zepto and jQuery conditionally loading for IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, zepto, fallback

Ok, So I'm calling my Zepto currently like this -

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.0/zepto.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/zepto.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Of course Zepto isn't built to work for IE so I need to fallback to jQuery for this browsers.

I'd guess my IE fallback would be similar to this -

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/***/1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Zepto suggest doing this -

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src=' + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') + '.js><\/script>')
</script>
```

How do I tie the two together?

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to use a script loader like yepnope.js. I gave it go and tried this:

```
<script>
    var fallback;
    if ('__proto__' in {}) {
        document.write('<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.0/zepto.min.js"><\/script>');
        fallback = 'zepto';
    } else {
        document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
        fallback = 'jquery';
    }
</script>
<script>
    window.$ || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/' + fallback + '.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Unfortunately I had to create a global var and separate out the scripts so that the first document.write() is blocking. Could also just use the `document.createElement('script')` and then do the fallback statement on `script.onerror`

Answer (score 0):

Improving on Herman's answer a hair:

```
<script>
  if ( '__proto__' in {} ) {
    document.write('<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.0/zepto.min.js"><\/script>');
    selfHosted = 'zepto';
  } else {
    document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
    selfHosted = 'jquery';
  }
</script>
<script>
  window.$ || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/' + selfHosted + '.js"><\/script>');
  delete selfHosted;
</script>
```

That cleans up the global var.

There is one gotcha with this approach though: CDNJS's Zepto doesn't include **additional modules** (see: https://github.com/madrobby/zepto#readme) that are **used by Foundation**. That will break tooltips - and most likely other JS plugins.
So use Foundation's own Zepto that comes patched with all the necessary modules:

```
<script>
  if( '__proto__' in {} ) {        
    selfHosted = 'zepto';
  } else {
    document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
    selfHosted = 'jquery';
  }
</script>
<script>
  window.$ || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/' + selfHosted + '.js"><\/script>');
  delete selfHosted;
</script>
```